Fraction with a numerator having a long exponent
In an expression as e.g.
\frac{A^{iB}}{C},
the fraction looks badly aligned.

I can manage for it to look better with the rather clumsy
\frac{A}{C}^{\!\text{\tiny $iB$}}.

Do you know a simpler method to get this result?
In other words, I would like to tell LaTeX to stretch the fraction line excluding the exponent/subscript/superscript of the last element in the numerator and/or denominator.
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
\hspace{0.33\textwidth}Inline:\hspace{0.1\textwidth}    $\frac{A^{iB}}{C}$
\begin{align*}
&\text{Displayed:}\qquad    \frac{A^{iB}}{C}
\end{align*}
    
\hspace{0.33\textwidth}Inline:\hspace{0.1\textwidth}    $\frac{A}{C}^{\!\text{\tiny $iB$}}$
\begin{align*}
&\text{Displayed:}\qquad    \frac{A}{C}^{\!\text{\tiny $iB$}}
\end{align*}
    \end{document}


Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Welcome. // For this short formula you can always rewrite inline $A^{iB}/C$ . // In general inline formulas can't be too complex. If they are, you better put them elsewhere, where you have space, AND refer to it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In addition to the already-mentioned $A^{iB}/C$, give \frac{1}{C} A^{iB} a try.

Hm, how you like to write some variable or delimiter following this strange fraction? I will not do this. The expression can become ambiguous.

Shortening the fraction line will make the formula very ambiguous.

There is also \frac{A^{iB}}{C^\phantom{iB}}.

Everything (more or less) can be done, but you should be very careful in adopting notation that's used by nobody else.
I've never seen fractions typeset the way you'd like to.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\weirdfrac}[3]{% #1=numerator, #2=exponent, #3=denominator
  \frac{#1^{\mathrlap{#2}}}{#3}\hphantom{^{#2}\!}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$\frac{A^{iB}}{C}+x \qquad \weirdfrac{A}{iB}{C}+x$
\end{center}
\[
\frac{A^{iB}}{C}+x \qquad \weirdfrac{A}{iB}{C}+x
\]

\end{document}


Your readers will be puzzled at the meaning of the weird fraction: perhaps the author wants to tell me that the whole fraction is raised to the exponent iB?
Now that you've seen the thing in context, go and sin no more. 

Thanks, \mathrlap is what I needed.
As for the ambiguity of the exponent, it is only in the code, not in the output.
As there are no parentheses, it is clear that the exponent is applied only to the numerator.

@Antonio I fully disagree.

For inline-math use cases, I would give both \frac{1}{C} A^{iB} and A^{iB}/C a try. Both methods will lead the A term to be typeset in text-style and the iB term to be typeset in script-style. In contrast, \frac{A^{iB}}{C} causes the A term to be typeset in script-style and the iB term to be typeset in scriptscript-style.
Aside: Script-style characters are usually 30% smaller than text-style characters, and scriptscript-style glyphs are 30% smaller than script-style characters.

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\frac{1}{C} A^{iB} \quad A^{iB}\!/C \quad \frac{A^{iB}}{C}$
\end{document}


You can use \! to add a small negative space of 3 math units after A^{iB}. Or, if you really want to display some part of the exponent outside the fraction bar, use \mathrlap from the mathtools package.
You'll need maybe an extra space after the fraction to avoid collisions with what follows.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for \mathrlap

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  &inline & displayed \\[1em]
  standard & $ \frac{A^{iB}}{C} $ &  $ \displaystyle \frac{A^{iB}}{C} $ \\[2em]
  with \verb|\!| & $ \frac{A^{iB}\!}{C} $ &  $ \displaystyle \frac{A^{iB}\!}{C} $ \\[2em]
  with \verb|\!\!| & $ \frac{A^{iB}\!\!}{C} $ &  $ \displaystyle \frac{A^{iB}\!\!}{C} $\\[2em]
  with \verb|\mathrlap| & $ \frac{A^{i \mathrlap{B}}}{C} $ &  $ \displaystyle \frac{A^{i \mathrlap{B}}\!\!}{C} $
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Thank you. \mathrlap is the tool I was looking for.
